# SQL counting duplicate emails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having issues with writing a query that can look for unique counts / duplicates under certain conditions.  I am trying to get counts at one time from the a table that is similar to this one:

```
|-P_key-|-----email-----|-act_no-|--Client--|
|   1   | joe@code.com  |    1   |   Jets   |
|   2   | bob@code.com  |    2   |   Jets   |
|   3   | sue@code.com  |  NULL  |   Jets   |
|   4   | joe@code.com  |    1   |   Bills  |
|   5   | bob@code.com  |    2   |   Bills  |
|   6   | bob@code.com  |    2   |   Giants |
|   7   | max@code.com  |    2   |   Giants |
|   8   | ben@code.com  |    5   |   Pats   |
```

the counts by client I am looking for are as follows:

1. count of total records for each client
2. count of total unique emails across clients
3. count of total unique account no's within client
4. count of total unique account no's across clients
5. count of blank account no's within client

I know that I could just use a group by and having in order to get these counts individually  like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(email)
FROM Table
GROUP BY EMAIL
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1;
```

but I was hoping to create a code that could return me a count of all at the same time.  I am using SQL server 2008.

The out put I was hoping to achieve was was follows (albeit the final data dosen't necessarily need to be pivoted as such):

```
 |                                  |  Jets  |  Bills | Giants |  Pats |
 | Total emails                     |   3    |    2   |    2   |   1   |
 | unique emails across projects    |   5    |    5   |    3   |   0   |
 | unique account_no across projects|   6    |    6   |    4   |   0   |
 | unique account_no within project |   0    |    0   |    2   |   0   |
 | blank account_no within project  |   1    |    0   |    0   |   0   |

 OR

 |        |  tot unique emails |  duped account_no's | etc...
 | Jets   |   3                |    5                |   
 |Bills   |   2                |    5                |   
 | Giants |   2                |    3                |    
 | Pats   |   1                |    0                |
```

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Comment: Can you show what the output that you want is, for the data in the question?

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't get the format in the structure you mention.  You can get it with each client on a row and five columns.

Second, you have very strange criteria.  If an email appears across multiple client, then the duped count for each client contains the total of the email everywhere.  Okay, but you need to both count the number of times the email occurs *and* determine whether it appears on multiple clients.

The solution is to calculate a bunch of intermediate results using window functions.  For instance, the `min()` and `max()` window functions are used to determine if an email or account number appears on multiple accounts.

Without a SQL Fiddle to test one, here is my best attempt:

```
select client,
       count(email) as NumEmails,
       sum(case when email_minclient <> email_maxclieint then email_cnt else 0
           end) as NumEmailsDuped,
       sum(case when actno_minclient <> actno_maxclieint then actno_cnt else 0
           end) as NumActnoDuped,
       sum(case when clientactno_cnt > 1 then clientactno_cnt else 0
           end) as NumActnoDupedWithin,
       sum(case when ActNo is null then 1 else 0 end) as NumActnoNull
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by email) as email_cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by act_no) as actno_cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by client, act_no) as clientactno_cnt,
             min(client) over (partition by email) as email_minclient,
             max(client) over (partition by email) as email_maxclient,
             min(client) over (partition by act_no) as email_minactno,
             max(client) over (partition by act_no) as email_maxactno
      from table t
     ) t
group by client;
```

Comment: I upgraded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result:

```
select client,
       count(email) as "Total emails",
       sum(case when email_minclient <> email_maxclient then email_cnt else 0
           end) as "unique emails across projects",
       sum(case when email_minclient <> email_maxclient then actno_cnt else 0
           end) as "unique account_no across projects",
       sum(case when clientactno_cnt > 1 then 1 else 0
           end) as "unique account_no within project",
       sum(case when act_no is null then 1 else 0 end) as "blank account_no within project "
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by email) as email_cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by act_no) as actno_cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by client, act_no) as clientactno_cnt,
             min(client) over (partition by email) as email_minclient,
             max(client) over (partition by email) as email_maxclient
      from table t  
     ) t
group by client
```

**Credits to Gordon Linoff**